# mi bot envia infinitos mensages

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy programando un juego en `discord.js` (reto personal ya se que no es bueno)

y cuando pones `!play` el bot envia

```
***
***
***
```

pero lo envía infinitamente ayuda

Aquí mi código:

```javascript
const discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new discord.Client();
p = false

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', msg => {
if (msg.content = "!play") {
p = true
msg.channel.send("***\n***\n***")
}
});

client.login('Privado no ver!');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (msg.content = "!play")
```

Siempre va a dar `true` porque es una asignación,  debes de utilizar el operador de comparación:

```
if (msg.content === "!play")
```

Suerte programando!

Answer (score 0):

Si no me equivoco el error estaría en `if (msg.content = "!play") {`, antes de `msg.content` lo he cambiado por `message.startsWith` y le das la orden al bot qué si un mensaje empieza por `!play` (en este caso) responda con el comando qué quieres qué responda, también he cambiado `msg` por `message` (lo veo más correcto), te dejo aquí el código correcto;

```
const discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new discord.Client();
p = false



client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', message => {
if (message.startsWith = "!play") {
p = true
message.channel.send("***\n***\n***")
}



});

client.login('Privado no ver!');
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

De partida la variable "p" no veo que sea de utilidad.

En cuanto al codigo así quedaría funcionando.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("ready", () => {
        console.log("Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!");
});
 
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if(message.content.startsWith("!play")) {
        message.channel.send("***\n***\n***");
    }
});

client.login('Privado no ver!');
```

Saludos!

Comment: Esto no es una respuesta: no explica el problema ni la solución.